# What is the best way to wrap Thread/Process in magic method __await__ to create awaitable class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I would like to create "awaitable" class instances. It will be useful when I have to use some db connectors which do not have `asyncio` wrappers. Also it is just interesting for me to better understand `asyncio` and `generators`.

I came to the following solutions:

**Solution #1**

```py
import asyncio
import threading
import time


async def ticker():
    """Just some kind of async ticker function."""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("tick tack sleep...")


class ThreadAwaitableWithToThread:
    """Illustrates how to wrap Thread in awaitable object."""
    def do_work(self):
        """Some target function for another Thread."""
        cur_th_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
        for i in range(5):
            print(f"Do work-{i} in {cur_th_name}")
            time.sleep(2)

        return "well done result!"

    def __await__(self):
        """Magic method to create awaitable object."""
        # to_thread is wrapper around run_in_executor
        result = yield from asyncio.to_thread(self.do_work).__await__()
        # The same without asyncio.to_thread:
        # result = yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, self.do_work).__await__()
        return result


async def amain():
    """Main asyncio entrypoint of the app."""
    t = asyncio.create_task(ticker())  # "daemon" task
    res = await ThreadAwaitableWithToThread()
    t.cancel()  # cancel "daemon" task
    print(f"Result: {res}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

The solution is based on `loop.run_in_executor`, probably it is the best solution, but I would like smth which is based on basic generators, rather than `asyncio` library functionality.

## Solution #2

```py
import asyncio
import threading
import time


async def ticker():
    """Just some kind of async ticker function."""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("tick tack sleep...")


class ThreadAwaitable:
    """Illustrates how to wrap Thread in awaitable object."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = threading.Event()  # sync between this and another thread

    def do_work(self):
        """Some target function for another Thread."""
        cur_th_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
        for i in range(5):
            print(f"Do work-{i} in {cur_th_name}")
            time.sleep(2)

        self.done.set()

    def __await__(self):
        """Magic method to create awaitable object."""
        th = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work)
        th.start()  # start another tread
        while True:
            if self.done.is_set():  # sync with another thread
                print(f"Work in {self.__class__.__name__} is done!")
                return "well done result!"

            # make loop switch between tasks while waiting another Thread to finish work.
            yield from asyncio.sleep(0.1).__await__()


async def amain():
    """Main asyncio entrypoint of the app."""
    t = asyncio.create_task(ticker())  # "daemon" task
    res = await ThreadAwaitable()
    t.cancel()  # cancel "daemon" task
    print(f"Result: {res}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

The solution is based on some kind of long polling with the help of `asyncio.sleep`, so the solution requires additional resources.

################################################################################

I would like to find some more elegant solution, I know about `select`, `selectors` libraries which allows to "listen to" sockets, if we attach Threads/Process to sockets we can switch between coroutines/generators with sockets inside. But docs of the libs is not very detailed and it will be some kind of self made `asyncio` (David Beazley in Pycon 2015). Is there any better solutions?

Comment: I don't feel like it really makes sense for an *object* to be asynchronous. Processes can be asynchronous, and objects are things, not processes.

Comment: I'd suggest creating an alternate constructor as a `@classmethod` that is an async method. In this method, you could get a bare instance using `__new__` and initialise it using asynchronous methods.

Comment: @matszwecja why not to use class instances as coroutines if `__await__` if it is part of Python language? E.g. this library use the mechanism https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite/blob/main/aiosqlite/core.py#L153

Comment: #1: You are already using the method `to_thread`.  It returns an awaitable object, with a `result` method that offers access to the returned value.  There seems to be no point in wrapping it inside yet another awaitable object, which doesn't appear to do anything other than make the result inaccessible.  #2: `loop.run_in_executor` returns an awaitable that, once again, offers access to the function's result.  For elegant solutions, my first thought is that I would rather use what's already there.  Is there some specific reason why you can't use the standard functions?

Comment: @PaulCornelius the idea is to make awaitable class instance, it is beneficial when you write some library, e.g. this one uses `__await__` github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite/blob/main/aiosqlite/core.py#L153 . I know that I can easily implement all requirements using only `run_in_executor` in some async function. I do this to better understand asyncio internal functionality, since it is basically generators + dispatcher which switch between them.